# Pause between pulsating circles

Tags: html, css, animation

i am trying to create an animation in CSS: two pulsating circles, the second circle should appear a bit later than the first circle. then pause and then again the same effect. i honestly can't figure out how to manage that (i don't mean animation delay property):

```css
.pulse {
  border: 60px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: pulsate 2s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  background-color: red;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="marker">
  <div class="pin"></div>
  <div class="pulse">
    <div id="pulse-outer">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Help would be appeciated!

i want to achieve the same effect like here on the right circle (but without the dot in the middle) -> https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/MaXxwv

Comment: Are you looking for something like this animation https://codepen.io/valentin/pen/sfnCE ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep using keyframes, and have two keyframes, where nothing happens in-between:

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  30% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(3);
  }

}
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work as i want. there are supposed to be two circles, the second one appear a bit later and they should overlap a bit. and then we have a short pause and again the same animation. so unfortunately it doesnt work with two keyframes, where nothing is happening

Comment: @helprin You still need to do some work yourself. You need two circles obviously, nesting them is probably just making things more complicated. I just adressed how you can do a pause.